# Doom Emacs Slowing Down because of Autocomplete

Tags: auto-complete-mode, doom

Whenever I start typing a word, Emacs tries to autocomplete it, and it slows down the app a lot.

I know the problem is the autocomplete because Emacs works fine normally.

Is there a way to remove the autocomplete suggestions? Its suggestions are not useful even if it did not slow down the app.

I tried turning off auto-complete-mode, but it did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To turn off auto completions you need to disable `company` in your `~/.doom.d/init.el`

```
   :completion
   company           ; the ultimate code completion backend
```

Comment: I want to disable this for normal text spelling, but not for coding.. I've been trying to do so for weeks and haven't figured it out. Do you know how I can set this up?

Comment: You can add a hook `(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'company-mode)`